# Property does not exist in the type of class which implements an interface, compiler error

Tags: typescript

In an app using TypeScript I am running into this problem that I am not sure how to solve or why it is happening.

In a module I have this type of code

```
// Api.ts
interface ApiInterface {
  signIn(user: object): AxiosPromise
  authenticated(): AxiosPromise
  getCurrentUser(): AxiosPromise
}

export class Api implements ApiInterface {
  public signIn() {
     ...
  }

  public authenticated() {
     ...
  }

  public getCurrentUser() {
     ...
  }    
}
```

But the problem is that I get a compilation error when in another file I try to use `Api` class like this:

```
import { Api } from './Api'

async function foo() {
  const isAuthenticated = await Api.authenticated() // ERROR
  ...
}
```

The error states that: **Property 'authenticated' does not exist on type 'typeof Api'.**

How do I get past this? Does the compiler not know that class Api implements ApiInterface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing the class `Api` the member `authenticated` exists on an instance of the class. You need to create an instance using the `new` operator

```
import { Api } from './Api'

async function foo() {
  const api = new Api();
  const isAuthenticated = await api.authenticated() // ERROR
  ...
}
```